# Phase of the Fourier Transform of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis

The Fourier Transform of this function

\begin{equation}
f(n)=u(n)-u(n-m)
\end{equation}

(where $u$ is the unity step)

is:

\begin{equation}
F(\omega)=\frac{\sin(\omega m/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}e^{-i(m-1)/2}
\end{equation}

The phase of $F$ is:
\begin{equation}
\phi=\angle{\frac{\sin(\omega m/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}}+\angle{e^{-i(m-1)/2}}
\end{equation}

My question is how to find the phase of:
\begin{equation}
\angle{\frac{\sin(\omega m/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a real number, $0$ or $\pi$ (modulo $2k\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$), depending on its sign. Since $e^{(0+2k\pi)\imath}=1$, and $e^{(\pi+2k\pi)\imath}=-1$, every positive real number can be written as $r = |r|e^{(0+2k\pi)\imath}$, and every negative real number as $r = |r|e^{(\pi+2k\pi)\imath}$. And there is an indeterminacy for $0$, since any phase would suit.

Finally, it is conventional to choose, for each number, a "simple" phase, for instance that looks constant, or "relatively continuous". Yet to be clean, on each non-zero number the  phase is defined (modulo $2k\pi$).

Comment: Thank you, but can you please elaborate how this is calculated?

Comment: I hope the details provided in the edited answer suit you fine.

Comment: Thanks you again your explanation is very helpful.